# How to export a reconstructed 3D model with texture using insight3d

Tags: blender, texture-mapping, 3d-modelling, vrml, 3d-reconstruction

I am using the open-source structure-from-motion program: [insight3D](http://insight3d.sourceforge.net/) to reconstruct a 3D model from a set of 2D images. I was able to export the resulting model as an VRML (.wrl) file but the texture and texture coordinates were not included when I inspected the resulting file in Blender/Meshlab. Has anyone been successful with exporting a textured model with insight3D? Thanks!